# How to create a form for new resources joined by has_many relationship in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activeadmin

I have a simple situation in my database. `Author` has_many `Books`.

With Active Admin I want to give users the ability to add new authors with their new books.

What I have right now looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Author do
  menu false

  actions :new, :create

  permit_params :books

  form do |f|
    f.has_many :books, new_record: true do |book|
      books.inputs 'book' do
        book.input :title
      end
    end
  end
end
```

however, when I go to the `new` action I'm getting the error

```
undefined method new_record? for nil:NilClass
```

pointing to

```
f.has_many :books, new_record: true do |book|
```

Do I need to override `new` and initialize new objects? What if I want to add multiple books dynamically? Is there a default solution for such a scenario?

Comment: Please read the "Spelling, grammar and punctuation are important! " section of "[ask]". Please use correct capitalization as SO is more like an online reference book and not a message board or forum; Grammar matters. "i" => "I", "active admin" => "Active Admin", "what i have..." => "What I have...", "im" => "I'm", etc.

Comment: why are you adding a new_record: true? I think it's not needed. Also did you add `accepts_nested_attributes_for  :books, :allow_destroy => true` in Author model?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you want your form to display inputs for a blank book without the user needing to click 'Add book' (default behavior) then pre-populate a book in new:

```
controller do
  def new
    build_resource
    resource.books << Book.new
    new!
  end
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple books dynamically" but the default JavaScript and 'Add' button should handle that.

As commented, you do need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :books` in the model and [extend your permit_params](https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html#setting-up-strong-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to tell the `Author` model to accept attributes of `Books`. You have to do it in the `model/author.rb`. Add the line -

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, :allow_destroy => true
```

Then you have permit the params in active admin model the right way to accept books attributes.

```
books_attributes: [:title]
```

Then you can add the form like below where activeadmin will dynamically handle creating new object or deleting one.

```
f.has_many :book do |b|
  b.inputs 'Books' do
    b.input :title
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing I could guess just from what you said is that you need to permite user params as well as books.
The database needs to INSERT INTO user the same way needs INSERT INTO books.
As Rails is a great framework and says "Convention over configuration", the only way we might give to you an apropriated answer is cheking your repository.

However "new_record?" method is always running when you try to INSERT INTO your database new data. You don't see it because it doesn't show nothing UNTIL you try INSERTING new datas without run another database migration.
In newest Rails version the migration is running as `rails db:migrate`.
Old Rails versions use `rake db:migrate`.

As I said, checking your repo is the best way to give you an appropriated answer. Cheers